# Checking google sheets for number bigger than 0 in every cell in a column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

and thank you in advance for your help.

I need to receive email if a cell is equal or bigger than 0. I populate this cell with =IMPORTXML every few hours. 
I need this to work for any cell in column L.
In the email i need to see the Cell L and the content of the Cell A of the same row.

Through digging around i managed to reach this.
It is apparent that is about half of what is needed.

```
thisfunction myNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var value = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("L2").getValue();
  if( value > 0 ) {
    var last = ScriptProperties.getProperty("last");
    value = value.toString();
    if( value != last ) {
      var email = Session.getUser().getEmail();
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, 'My Notification',
                        'new value: '+value+'\n\n'+ss.getUrl ());
      ScriptProperties.setProperty("last", value);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will go through all rows with data in Sheet1 and send an email if column L is greater than 0.
It will also keep the newer Script Properties of the PropertiesService updated.

```
var sp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();


function myNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var data = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getDataRange().getValues();
  var targetCell = 11; // L

  function sendMail(row) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(
      Session.getUser().getEmail(), 
      'My Notification',
      'new value: ' + row[targetCell] + '\nin: ' + row[0] + '\n' + ss.getUrl ());
    return row;
  };

  function updateScriptProperties(row) {
    sp.setProperty(row[0], row[targetCell]);
    return row;
  };

  function aChanged(row) {
    return sp.getProperty(row[0]) != row[targetCell];
  };

  function colLGreater0(row) {return row[targetCell] > 0;};

  data.filter(colLGreater0)
      .filter(aChanged)
      .map(sendMail)
      .map(updateScriptProperties);
};
```